# Why does Erase give ERROR 999999 (Error executing function Invalid Topology Negative point valence)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, file-geodatabase, topology, error-999999

I am getting the following error when I try to erase a set of data from a file within a gdb. Any idea on what to do? I have done repair geometry multiple times on the input/erase datasets. I have 16GB RAM and close to a TB of free space. The dataset is approx 1.6m records. Arcmap 10 sp3. BTW how do I see the size of a dataset within a gdb?

> Executing (Erase): Erase
>   D:\SCRATCH\Projects\106\data\7_Merge.gdb\mergeall_1
>   D:\SCRATCH\Projects\106\data\5b_ReclassVector.gdb\Lidar_d2b
>   d:\SCRATCH\Projects\106\data\6_Erase.gdb\srtm_m10m_e "1 Meters" Start
>   Time: Sat Oct 15 02:53:38 2011 Reading Features... Processing Tiles...
>   ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Invalid Topology [Negative
>   point valence.] Failed to execute (Erase).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic reason for this seems to be just the size of the dataset.

See **[Why Intersect gives ERROR 999999: Error executing function Invalid Topology [Too many lineseg endpoints]?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16110/issues-with-large-datasets)**

There are some other workarounds, none of them bulletproof, suggested in **[Invalid Topology [Topoengine error] from ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60250/invalid-topology-topoengine-error-arcgis-10-1/90531#90531)**

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the 999999 error.   I agree, probably the size of the dataset.  I've encountered that error a few times with complicated buffers.   Not sure if it's memory related.   I have gotten that error on a machine with 2gb ram, then tried it on a different one with 4gb and it's successful.
16gb ram?   You're running 64bit?