# Writing extent of each grid cell in fishnet to its attribute table using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, extents, vector-grid

I have generated a grid (polygons 1000x1000m) using Fishnet in ArcGIS 10.8. I am intending to add top left and bottom right coordinates of **each grid cell** in respective fields I have added in the attribute table.

How would I derive these values utilizing the 'Field Calculator' (or by other means) and populate the corresponding fields.

I am aware of [Obtaining extent of each polygon in shapefile using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16520) which is a closely related question but the solution given in response to the question produced the desired results in the Python window instead of the attribute table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool "Calculate Geometry Attributes" offers options such as:

- Minimum x-coordinate,
- Maximum x-coordinate,
- Minimum y-coordinate,
- Maximum y-coordinate.

I think this should suit your need.