# Invalid Topology: Cannot Open Cache File when trying to do a dissolve

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, topology, dissolve

I'm trying to perform a dissolve to take some data that is at the Census Block level to the County level. I'm dissolving by the County ID and doing a Statistic Field for various attributes (1 SUM, 2 MEANS, 1 COUNT).

However, it keeps failing with this error.

It's a fairly large data-set, since its census blocks.

I'm working in ArcMap.

Any help?

Comment: Try a repair geometry first before dissolving and look at your temporary storage locations (OS environment TMP) to see if you have any storage space, is your input data shapefile or geodatabase? Try a definition query or selection in ArcMap to limit the number of input features and see if that works.

Comment: What's the complete error message?  What's the precise syntax you gave to Dissolve?  It may or may not be https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/90531/115